# c++ compile error when initializating an object

Tags: c++

Am new to c++ and need help in resolving an error.
The code below compiles fine on older Sun versions (CC 5.3 and 5.8). 
I put a comment at line where error is occuring.
Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks so much.
-RW

Unix version: SunOS ut51278 5.10 Generic_141444-09 sun4u sparc SUNW,SPARC-Enterprise
Compiler version: CC: Sun C++ 5.11 SunOS_sparc 2010/08/13

database.h:

```
#include <dbserver.h> 
#include <dbstoredproc.h> 
#include "dbsql.h" 

class Database : public DBServer 
{ 
        public : 
                DBSql SQL( const char* sqlCmd ); 
                DBSql SQL( const std::string& sqlCmd ); 
                DBSql Table( const char* tableName );                         
                DBSql Table( const std::string& tableName ); 
                DBStoredProc storedProc( const char* spName ); 
                DBStoredProc storedProc( const std::string& tableName ); 
};
```

dbsql.h:

```
 #include <string> 
#include "dbaccess.h" 
#include "dbtable.h" 

class DBSql : public DBAccess 
{ 
public: 
        DBSql(DBServer *pServer,const char *sql) ; 
        DBSql(DBServer *pServer,const std::string& sql); 
        DBSql(DBSql& dbSql); 
        DBSql& operator=(DBSql& dbSql); 
        virtual DBTable getResultSet(); 
protected: 
        DBSql(); 
        void init(DBServer *pServer,const std::string& sql); 

};
```

Error is occuring in database.cpp... see comment with error message....

database.cpp:

```
#include <database.h> 
#include "dbsql.h" 
using namespace std; 

DBSql Database::Table( const char* tableName ) 
{ 
     return Table( string( tableName ) );  // Error: "Cannot use DBSql to initialize DBSql."
} 
DBSql Database::Table( const string& tableName ) 
{ 
      string sqlCmd = "select * from " + tableName; 
      return SQL( sqlCmd.c_str() );   

} 
DBSql Database::SQL( const char* sqlCmd ) 
{ 
      return DBSql(this,sqlCmd);           
} 
DBSql Database::SQL( const string& sqlCmd ) 
{ 
      return SQL( sqlCmd.c_str() );        
} 
DBStoredProc Database::storedProc( const char* spName ) 
{ 
     return DBStoredProc( this, spName ); 
} 
DBStoredProc Database::storedProc( const std::string& spName ) 
{ 
    return DBStoredProc( this, spName ); 
}
```

dbsql.cpp:

```
#include "dbsql.h" 
#include "dbcommon.h" 
using namespace std; 
using namespace ORACLE; 

DBSql::DBSql(DBServer *pServer,const char* sql) 
{ 
   init(pServer,string(sql)); 
} 
DBSql::DBSql(DBServer *pServer,const string& sql) 
{ 
   init(pServer,sql); 
} 
DBSql::DBSql(DBSql& dbSql) 
 : DBAccess(dbSql) 
{ 

} 
DBSql& DBSql::operator=(DBSql& dbSql) 
{ 
  DBAccess::assign(dbSql); 
  return *this; 
} 
DBSql::DBSql() 
{ 
} 
void DBSql::init(DBServer *pServer,const string& sql) 
{ 
   execSQL(pServer,sql.c_str()); 
} 

DBTable DBSql::getResultSet() 
{ 
DBTable result; 
  if(DBAccess::getResultSet(false)) 
  { 
  //In order to prevent DBAccess from closing the previous result set, pass false to 
  //getResultSet 
    result = DBTable(m_pStmt,m_pResultSet,true); // Pass true to DBTable to allow it       
    m_pStmt = NULL;                              //  to control the statement. 
  } 
  m_pResultSet = NULL; 
  return result; 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Change:

```
DBSql(DBSql& dbSql);
```

To:

```
DBSql(DBSql const & dbSql);
```

The call `Table( string( tableName ) )` produces a temporary which needs to be copied, using a copy constructor, in order to be returned. Since the value is temporary, you can only get a *const* reference to it - and your copy constructor doesn't accept that.

Since your copy constructor and assignment operator don't actually *do* anything, you could just as well leave them out. If you keep them, you should also change `DBSql& operator=(DBSql& dbSql);` to take a const reference - `DBSql& operator=(DBSql const & dbSql);` - and make the same changes in the parent class copy construcor and assignment operator.